# R Moving Average based on Product (Or Start over new moving average values when I see new Prododuct)

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I tried to find the answer before I post this question but not lucky. 
I have a big dataset with 100s of Products. I would like to compute 'Moving Averages' based on product. 
I am using this below code but MA is not re-setting while I am moving from one product to other product.

Is it possible to compute MA based on product? Please help

```
library(TTR)
df <- data.frame(product=c('milk','milk','milk','milk','milk','milk','milk','milk',
                           'eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs'), 
                 sales=c(404,410,500,520,480,400,590,500,
                        400,499,520,500,444,400,570,580
                       ));
df$sma2 <- SMA(df[,"sales"],3)
```

Comment: You may need a group by operation `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, SMA(sales, 3), by = product]` or `base R` with `base R` `aggregate(sales~product, df, SMA, n=3)`

Comment: or `library(dplyr)` with `df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(m_avg = SMA(sales, 3))`